# Changing the ref_id of a url to deliver tailor-made video content to users. Brightcove advanced embed code + Idomoo logic

Tags: javascript, html5-video, brightcove

Hello wise and helpful people of StackOverflow. I am using a combination of Brightcove as a video player and the sample code below is from a third-party company that I am supposed to use it with. 
The main concept of what I am trying to achieve is the ability to deliver tailor-made video content to specific users by changing the ref_Id of the video on the URL. I have received sample code and instructions but I am still not sure how to go about this. I would very much appreciate all the help and insights I can get as I think this is a great project that's pretty cool in my opinion. 
Basically I need to find out how to change the ref_Id of the URL so a different video can be played.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF8">

    <!-- Bootstrap plugin & jquery plugin -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>


    <title>Landing-Page</title>


</head>

<body>
<div class="title">
    <h1>LP Sample</h1>
</div>

<!-- video tag -->
<div class="video-container">
    <video id="myPlayer"
           crossorigin
           data-account="5387496927001"
           data-player="S1WpvbFwlW"
           data-embed="default"
           data-application-id
           class="video-js" controls
           autoplay
           width="1280"
           height="720">
    </video>


    <!--end video tag -->
    <br/>
    <!--link buttons-->
    <div class="link">
        <a id="movie2" href="javascript:" onclick="changeVideo()">Turn on audio description</a>
        <a id="movie1" href="javascript:" onclick="openVideo()">Turn off audio description</a>
    </div>
    <!--end link buttons-->
    <div class="button">
        <button id="get-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Click Here</button>
    </div>

    <!--player script-->
    <script src="//players.brightcove.net/5387496927001/S1WpvbFwlW_default/index.min.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
<script>


    /**
     * the function gets the ID of the video from the url (the hashID is the refId of the video)
     * */
    function getParameterByName(hashId) {
        var url = window.location.href;

        hashId = hashId.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + hashId + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }


    /**
     * The Url query contain accountID/statsID/ClipID (have to be in this format)
     * refId = all Url query
     * hashOnly = ClipID
     * */
    var refId = getParameterByName('ref_id');
    var params = refId.split("/");
    var hashOnly = params[2];
    var count = 0;

    var myPlayer;
    var srcPath;
    var option;
    var on;
    var off;
    var isOn = false;
    var stats = "stats-usa.idomoo.com";


    /**
     * When the player load get the video object from the reference video 0000(have to set the ref video " 0000" in brightcove site)
     * src value get the remote assets source we set in the brightcove site.
     * the srcPth value get the path before the "0000/" (have to include the "0000/")
     * finally the function set the new video in the player.
     * */
    videojs("myPlayer").ready(function () {
        myPlayer = this;


        //set video on start
        myPlayer.catalog.getVideo("ref:0000", function (error, video) {

            myPlayer.catalog.load(video);

            //get path
            var src = video.sources[0].src;
            srcPath = src.substring(0, src.indexOf("0000/"));

            myPlayer.mediainfo.name = "";

            //set the poster img have to in the same path and same name
            myPlayer.poster(srcPath + refId + ".jpg");

            //diplay the CC button
            myPlayer.mediainfo.textTracks = [
                {

                    "src": srcPath + refId + "_en.vtt",
                    "srclang": "en",
                    "label": "en",
                    "kind": "captions",
                    "mime_type": "text/vtt"
                }
            ];


            option =
                {

                    kind: "captions",
                    label: "EN",
                    language: "en",
                    src: srcPath + refId + "_en.vtt"
                };
            //Delete all the textTracks
            var oldTracks = myPlayer.remoteTextTracks();
            var i = oldTracks.length;
            while (i--) {
                myPlayer.removeRemoteTextTrack(oldTracks[i]);
            }
            ;

            //Add the caption object(option)
            myPlayer.addRemoteTextTrack(option, true);


            myPlayer.src({"type": "video/mp4", "src": srcPath + refId + ".mp4"});
            myPlayer.play();
        });
    });

    /**
     * open video function --> loads the main video (without descriptive audio) to the player
     */
    function openVideo() {
        //remove older caption and set a new one
        var oldTracks = myPlayer.remoteTextTracks();
        var i = oldTracks.length;
        while (i--) {
            myPlayer.removeRemoteTextTrack(oldTracks[i]);
        }
        ;


        off =
            {

                kind: "captions",
                label: "en",
                language: "en",
                src: srcPath + refId + "_en.vtt"
            };

        myPlayer.addRemoteTextTrack(off, true);

        myPlayer.src({"type": "video/mp4", "src": srcPath + refId + ".mp4"});
        myPlayer.play();

        count = 0;
        $("#movie1").hide();
        $("#movie2").show();
        isOn = false;
        $("button.vjs-caption-toggle-control.vjs-icon-captions.vjs-control").removeClass("vjs-selected");
    }

    /**
     * change video function --> loads the video with refID + "da"
     * refID + "da" is the descriptive audio video version of the main audio
     */
    function changeVideo() {
        //remove older caption and set a new one
        var oldTracks = myPlayer.remoteTextTracks();
        var i = oldTracks.length;
        while (i--) {
            myPlayer.removeRemoteTextTrack(oldTracks[i]);
        }
        ;

        on =
            {

                kind: "captions",
                label: "en",
                language: "en",
                src: srcPath + refId + "da_en.vtt"
            };

        myPlayer.addRemoteTextTrack(on, true);


        myPlayer.src({"type": "video/mp4", "src": srcPath + refId + "da.mp4"});
        myPlayer.play();


        count = 0;
        $("#movie2").hide();
        $("#movie1").show();
        isOn = true;
        $("button.vjs-caption-toggle-control.vjs-icon-captions.vjs-control").removeClass("vjs-selected");

    }


    /**
     * That function run until get the srcPath value from the video object from the brightcove
     * and set it in href attribute in the transcript.
     * the transcript html have to be in the same bucket and same name of the ClipID
     */
    function waitForSrcPath() {
        if (srcPath == null) {
            setTimeout(waitForSrcPath, 50);
            return;
        }
    }

    var isFinished = false;
    var stopInterval;
    /**
     *  send Get request to idomoo analytics every 10 percent start at 0 until 100
     */
    function analyticsVideoHandle() {
        var currentTime = myPlayer.currentTime();
        var videoTime = myPlayer.duration();


        var timePercent = currentTime / videoTime;
        var timeTemp = Math.ceil(timePercent * 10) * 10;
        timeTemp = timeTemp - 10;

        if (count != 0 && count <= timeTemp) {
            count = timeTemp;
        }

        var rawTimeTemp = timePercent * 100;
        rawTimeTemp = Math.floor(rawTimeTemp);


        if (isOn) {
            if (((Math.floor(rawTimeTemp) === timeTemp && count === timeTemp) || timePercent === 1) && !isFinished) {
                if (timePercent != 1) {
                    count = count + 10;
                    $.ajax({
                        'url': 'https://' + stats + '/?pid=' + params[0] + '&eiid=' + params[1] + '&eid=' + hashOnly + 'da&atype=0&cvprogress=' + timeTemp,
                        'type': 'GET'
                    });
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        'url': 'https://' + stats + '/?pid=' + params[0] + '&eiid=' + params[1] + '&eid=' + hashOnly + 'da&atype=0&cvprogress=' + 100,
                        'type': 'GET'
                    });
                    isFinished = true;
                    if (stop != null) {

                        clearInterval(stopInterval);
                    }
                    return;

                }
            }
        } else {
            if (((Math.floor(rawTimeTemp) === timeTemp && count === timeTemp) || timePercent === 1) && !isFinished) {
                if (timePercent != 1) {
                    count = count + 10;
                    $.ajax({
                        'url': 'https://' + stats + '/?pid=' + params[0] + '&eiid=' + params[1] + '&eid=' + hashOnly + '&atype=0&cvprogress=' + timeTemp,
                        'type': 'GET'
                    });
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        'url': 'https://' + stats + '/?pid=' + params[0] + '&eiid=' + params[1] + '&eid=' + hashOnly + '&atype=0&cvprogress=' + 100,
                        'type': 'GET'
                    });
                    isFinished = true;
                    if (stop != null) {

                        clearInterval(stopInterval);
                    }
                    return;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send GET request to Idomoo analytics when the landing page load
     */
    function analyticsOnLoad() {
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'https://' + stats + '/?pid=' + params[0] + '&eiid=' + params[1] + '&eid=' + hashOnly + '&atype=1&cfatype=1&landingPageVisited=' + window.location.href.split('?')[0],
            'type': 'GET'
        });
    }

    /**
     * When click on the button "Click Here" send GET request to Idomoo analytics
     */
    function analyticsOnClick() {
        $("#get-btn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                'url': 'https://' + stats + '/?pid=' + params[0] + '&eiid=' + params[1] + '&eid=' + hashOnly + '&atype=1&cfatype=1&ccfan=CLICKHERE',
                'type': 'GET'
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set to the player the attribute "data-customguid"
     * run the function analyticsVideoHandle() every 50 milliseconds to check every change in video time until the video finish
     */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        waitForSrcPath();
        $("#myPlayer").attr("data-customguid", "ref:" + refId);
        analyticsOnLoad();
        analyticsOnClick();
        stopInterval = setInterval(function () {
            analyticsVideoHandle();
        }, 100);


    });


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: *bump for this *